# JPA OneToMany bi-directional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know that there is many question about it but i can not find a good answered for my problem .

I am using Jboss as 7, Spring and Hibernate (4) as JPA 2.0 provider so i have got simple @OneToMany bi-directional relationship :

I have got super class person like that:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z ]*", message = "must contain only letters and spaces")
private String name;  


public Person(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}
```

And class Member:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class Member extends Person implements Serializable
{
   /** Default value included to remove warning. Remove or modify at will. **/
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   @NotNull
   @NotEmpty
   @Email
   private String email;

   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 10, max = 12)
   @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 12)
   @Column(name = "phone_number")
   private String phoneNumber;

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL , mappedBy="member" , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Order> orders;
```

And also class Order:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private float price; 

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private Member member;

private String name;
```

So i think that it is a good configuration, but i test this application in HSQL in memory and i have got error :

```
Hibernate: alter table Order drop constraint FK48E972E548C740B
2012-09-20 16:25:37 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Order drop constraint FK48E972E548C740B
2012-09-20 16:25:37 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Blad skladniowy w wyrazeniu SQL "ALTER TABLE ORDER[*] DROP CONSTRAINT FK48E972E548C740B "; oczekiwano "identifier"
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE ORDER[*] DROP CONSTRAINT FK48E972E548C740B "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table Order drop constraint FK48E972E548C740B [42001-165]
```

And also :

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ORDER[*] (ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR(255), PRICE FLOAT NOT NULL, MEMBER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

And my JUnit test failed i dont know what is wrong with this configuration ...

this is my simply junit :

```
  @Test
public void testInsertWithOrder(){
    Order order = new Order(20.0f, "first stuff");
    Order order2 = new Order(40.0f, "secondary stuff");
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    orders.add(order2);
    orders.add(order);

    Member member = new Member("Member name", "member23@gmail.com", "2125552141", orders);

    memberDao.register(member);

    List<Member> members = memberDao.findAllOrderedByName();

    Assert.assertNotNull(members);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, members.size());     

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change table name from 'order' to something different, like PersonOrder

Comment: Yes, `user1516873` is right, If you use `MySqL`, `Order` word is reserved word of MySQL.

Comment: +1 you have got right. But i still have got error: `NULL not allowed for column "MEMBER_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into UOrder (id, member_id, name, price) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23502-165]`

Comment: thanks user1516873, same keyword is reserved on PostgreSQL, too

Comment: that applies to H2 as well

Answer (score 1):

In your `member` in `Order` Class, there are missing `@JoinColumn` annotation. Try as below.

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "memberId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Member member;
```

Comment: I change Order to **UOrder** but i have got another error : NULL not allowed for column "MEMBER_ID"; SQL statement: insert into UOrder (id, member_id, name, price) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23502-165] I dont understand why my id is generated by database GenerationType.IDENTITY
Any idea ??

Comment: In H2 Reserved Keywork, `Order` is one of them; see http://www.scribd.com/doc/88837291/224/Keywords-Reserved-Words        `CROSS, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DISTINCT, EXCEPT, EXISTS, FALSE, FOR, FROM, FULL,GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTERSECT, IS, JOIN, LIKE, LIMIT, MINUS, NATURAL, NOT, NULL, ON, ORDER, PRIMARY, ROWNUM,SELECT, SYSDATE, SYSTIME, SYSTIMESTAMP, TODAY, TRUE, UNION, UNIQUE, WHERE`

Comment: Yes i am so stupid :) it is so easy ... i change my class name to UOrder

Comment: :) It just use `@Table(name="UOrder")`

Comment: Thre is no reference `member` instance in `order` order.setMember(member) in your `testInsertWithOrder()` method. Fristly, try to learn JPA/OR Mapping. You have to set `member instance` for all of `order instance` eg; `order, order2' in your code

Comment: I do not understood i thinkig if i add casade type.All so when i persist entity Member  orders will persist after.

Comment: Did you try as above? Now you are using `OneToMany bidirectional` reference instance will have each other.(vise visa)

Answer (score 1):

@CycDemo

I am just figure it out and in my constuctor i now have got :

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL , mappedBy="member" , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UOrder> orders = new ArrayList<UOrder>();



       public Member(String name, String email, String phoneNumber ,List<UOrder> orders) {
       super(name);
       this.orders = orders;
       this.email = email;
       for(UOrder o : orders){
           o.setMember(this);          
       }
       this.orders = orders;

   }
```

Ant this is it what i need :)))